# How to create multiple instance of activity outside of activity

Tags: android, geofencing

Hi after searching I could not able to getting answer of how to create multiple instance of activity.

1.I have one broadcast receiver that handle the incoming location fencing  send by google play service.

2.Next In broadcast receiver some time it will receive the set of Geofence here I need to start the multiple instance of the same activity but I could not able actually.

I start drop the code below :

```
public class GeoFenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context mContext;

private HistoryDAO mHistoryDAO;

public GeoFenceReceiver() {
}

private Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}

private void initializeHistoryDAO() {
    if(mHistoryDAO == null){
        mHistoryDAO = new HistoryDAO(getContext());
    }
}

private boolean hasDataAccess(){
    return mHistoryDAO != null;
}

private HistoryDAO getHistroyDAO(){
    if(!hasDataAccess()){
        initializeHistoryDAO();
    }
    return mHistoryDAO;
}

private HistoryData getRawData(int rowID){
    List<HistoryData> listDatas = getHistroyDAO().getHistoryById(rowID);
    if (listDatas != null && listDatas.size() > 0) {
        return listDatas.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

private void releaseDataAccess(){
    if(hasDataAccess()){
        mHistoryDAO.releaseHelper();
    }
}

private String getString(int resID,Object... formatArgs){
    return getContext().getString(resID,formatArgs);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    mContext = context;

    //set up the dao
    initializeHistoryDAO();

    //get intent action
    String action = intent.getAction();

    // Handle the intent send by google play service for receive the geo fence transition 
    if(TextUtils.equals(action,GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_RECEIVED)){

        handleReceiveGeofence(context, intent);

    } else if (TextUtils.equals(action, SnoozeUtils.ACTION_SNOOZE_RECEIVER)) {

        // handle the incomming intent send by system alarm manager
        // This intent contain the reminder id/ history plain java object in
        // string json format that we send it to the
        // pop up of reminder for show the reminder details.

        handleSnoozeAction(context, intent);
    }
    //release data connection
    releaseDataAccess();


}
```

see in above **handleReceiveGeofence(context, intent);** when we receive the new fencing we handle here.

```
 /**
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param intent
 */
private void handleReceiveGeofence(Context context, Intent intent){
    mContext = context;

    // Create a local broadcast Intent
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    // Give it the category for all intents sent by the Intent Service
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

     // First check for errors
    if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {

       // handle any error code here...

    // If there's no error, get the transition type and create a notification
    } else {

        //play notification sound
        notificationSound();

        //vibrart the device 
        notificationVibration();

        // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
        int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

        // Test that a valid transition was reported
        if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                ||(transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

            //transition type 
            String transitionType = getTransitionString(transition);

            // Post a notification
            List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);

            String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];

            for (int index = 0; index < geofences.size() ; index++) {
                geofenceIds[index] = geofences.get(index).getRequestId();
                showNotification(transition,String.valueOf(geofences.get(index).getRequestId()));
            }
            // geofence id 
            String ids = TextUtils.join(GeofenceUtils.GEOFENCE_ID_DELIMITER,geofenceIds);

            if(BackAppApplication.getInstance().getAppDebugMode()){
                sendNotification(transitionType, ids);  
            }
            // Log the transition type and a message
            Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_title,transitionType,ids));

            Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text));

        // An invalid transition was reported
        } else {
            // Always log as an error
            Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, transition));
        }
    }
}
```

3.Now see in above code ***List geofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);***

Above List contains the collection of geofence details now If it contains the single item then I have

no issue to display/ start activity It work fine.

But the problem occurred when more than one geofence come in broadcast intent. It only show the one

instance of activity instead of stack of the activity.

4.Next step the main area for display the activity.

```
public synchronized void showNotification(final int transitionType,final String reminderID){

    // we check here whether the reminder id exits with active on or off
    HistoryData mData = getRawData(Integer.parseInt(reminderID));
    if (mData != null && mData.isActive()) {

        //check the transition type if it is enter check the grace time
        if (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

            if (Utility.checkDateDifferent(mData.getTimeStamp()) < GeofenceUtils.MIN_PROXALERT_INTERVAL) {

                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getContext(),TransitionErrorPopUp.class);
                mIntent.putExtra(AbsReminderPopUp.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID,reminderID);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
                return ;
            }
        }

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(getContext(),ReminderPopUp.class);
        mIntent.putExtra(AbsReminderPopUp.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID,reminderID);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        getContext().startActivity(mIntent);

    }
}
```

5.I have been tried by removing the FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK

6.As I know start activity from outside of activity component need to set the flag

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

***I face this issues last three days I finally post here might be some one can help me.***